# QTextEdit crash on appending text

Tags: c++, qt

I am developing an application which run scripts and display scripts results in a "Shell Window". This window contains a `QTextEdit` where all script output is appended.

The script may append data to two `QTextStream`: `out` and `err`.

To let the `QTextStream` use the `QTextEdit` as an output I used the `TextEditIODevice` class (source below).

The script is run in a separated thread in the `VirtualMachine` class (source not provided).

My problem is that the program randomly crash while appending data to the `QTextEdit`.

Here is a screen shoot of the crash:

[image: debugger]

Does someone already had this problem ? Do you know how to solve it ?

Thanks for your help solving this !

---

## TextEditIODevice

### Header file

```
class TextEditIODevice : public QIODevice
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TextEditIODevice(QTextEdit * qTextEdit, QColor color, QObject * parent);

    virtual ~TextEditIODevice();

protected:
    qint64 readData(char *data, qint64 maxlen);

    qint64 writeData(const char *data, qint64 len);

private:
    /**
     * @brief Pointer to QTextEdit
     */
    QPointer<QTextEdit> textEdit;

    /**
     * @brief Text color
     */
    QColor color;

    /**
     * @brief Shared pointer to QTextEdit associated mutex
     */
    QSharedPointer<QMutex> mutex;

    /**
     * @brief Storage for QTextEdit associated mutexes
     */
    static QMap<QPointer<QTextEdit>, QSharedPointer<QMutex>> mutexes;
};
```

### Source file

```
QMap<QPointer<QTextEdit>, QSharedPointer<QMutex>> TextEditIODevice::mutexes;

TextEditIODevice::TextEditIODevice(QTextEdit * qTextEdit, QColor color, QObject * parent) :
    QIODevice(parent),
    textEdit(qTextEdit),
    color(color)
{
    open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);

    qRegisterMetaType<QTextCharFormat>("QTextCharFormat");
    qRegisterMetaType<QTextBlock>("QTextBlock");
    qRegisterMetaType<QTextCursor>("QTextCursor");

    if(mutexes.contains(textEdit))
    {
        qDebug() << QString("[%1] Reuse previously created mutex").arg(textEdit->objectName());
        mutex = mutexes[textEdit];
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << QString("[%1] Create mutex").arg(textEdit->objectName());
        mutex = QSharedPointer<QMutex>(new QMutex());
        mutexes.insert(textEdit, mutex);
    }
}

TextEditIODevice::~TextEditIODevice()
{
}

qint64 TextEditIODevice::readData(char *data, qint64 maxlen)
{
    Q_UNUSED(data);
    Q_UNUSED(maxlen);
    return 0;
}



qint64 TextEditIODevice::writeData(const char *data, qint64 len)
{
    if(textEdit)
    {
        qDebug() << QString("[%1] Wait for lock").arg(textEdit->objectName());
        mutex->lock();
        qDebug() << QString("[%1] Append text : %2").arg(textEdit->objectName()).arg(data);
        const QColor lastColor = textEdit->textColor();
        textEdit->setTextColor(color);
        textEdit->append(QString(data));
        textEdit->setTextColor(lastColor);
        qDebug() << QString("[%1] Unlock mutex").arg(textEdit->objectName());
        mutex->unlock();
    }

    return len;
}
```

Comment: Could it be that `writeData` runs in a worker thread? You could use signal/slot mechanism to make sure it runs in the GUI thread.

Comment: Do you know how I may check that writeData is running in the worker thread, or in the GUI thread ?

Comment: From where is it called?

Comment: Usually it is called from the VirtualMachine thread. Like this: `outputStream << "text" << endl`.`outputStream` is a `QTextStream` backed by the `TextEditIODevice`.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#qobject-reentrancy), "QWidget and all its subclasses are not reentrant. They can only be used from the main thread." That means you have to make sure that the calls to `textEdit->append` et.al. are running in the main/GUI thread. The easiest way is probably to put this in a slot, and emit a signal, as the signal/slot mechanism provides thread synchronization.

Comment: Ok, I add a stream class to communicate with the original stream using signals and slots. I works now ! Thank you :)